# PixelCopy on pre-Nougat devices

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-pixel-copy

I would like to use the functionality of `PixelCopy` (`Image` to bitmap) on pre-Nougat devices but unfortunately it is not available. Is there some compat method available which does the same thing? I'm thinking that if it is not available, I will have to use reflection to get the `ThreadedRenderer` and reimplement PixelCopy that way. Has anyone thought of any better solutions?

Edit: This is different than the possible duplicate because it is about general `Image` not `SurfaceView`, so canvas solutions aren't relevant to it.

Comment: Seeing as the `ThreadedRenderer.copySurfaceInto()` method also doesn't exist below Nougat, I'm not sure how far reflection will get you. The implementation is also in C++.

Comment: Are you sure `copySurfaceInto` doesn't exist below Nougat? The `ThreadedRenderer` class itself appears to exist pre-Nougat.

Comment: Also, it's not a duplicate. My question is not about Views, but about a general `Surface` which can come from an `InputReader` rather than a `SurfaceView`

Comment: Take a look for yourself: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/view/ThreadedRenderer.java.

Comment: Ok, I see. But `copyLayerInto` method exists and a hardware layer can be retrieved from an `Image`. I will update the question to say `Image` rather than `Surface`

Comment: Actually given that change, there does seem to be some `Image` to `Bitmap` questions out there, so I will close this.